# emacs 24 color-theme not working

Tags: emacs, putty, color-theme

I'm running emacs 24 and trying to change the colour theme but it's not working.

When I start emacs it displays in the default colours. I do `M-x load-theme RET tango RET` and the colours revert to white on a black background (other themes do the same thing).

I'm running emacs on debian wheezy through a putty window on a Windows 7 host. I've tried a local instance on debian with no change. I've tried both a pre-built package and building directly from a git mirror.

I'm something of an emacs newbie so it's possible I'm doing something stupid. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried just plain old `M-x color-theme RET` and then pressing the tab key or whatever the option is next?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a command M-x color-theme

Comment: Well, that may be your problem -- i.e., color-theme is not properly installed, or it is not set up correctly.

Comment: Do you have something like this in your `.emacs` file?:   `(require 'color-theme)` `(color-theme-initialize)` `(color-theme-robin-hood)`.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood -- your title says `color-theme`.  There is no `tango` color theme included within `color-theme` by default:  http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/    Have you installed separately a theme named `tango`?

Comment: Is this what you are trying to use from the wiki page, and did you download it and place it in your load path?  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/color-theme-tango.el

Comment: color-theme is installed by default in emacs24. It turns out it was a problem with Putty after all and emacs was fine. Sorry!